# Application of Sylow Theorems.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have a group theory exam coming up so I was reviewing through my textbook and I stumbled across a problem that looked interesting:

Let $p < q$ be two primes and $G$ be a group of order $pq^3$. Show that $G$ has a normal subgroup.

I wrote a solution, but I wanted to double check if it made sense.

Solution:

By the first Sylow theorem, G has Sylow p-subgroups of order $p$ and $q^3$.

So let $n_p$ represent the number of Sylow subgroups of order $p$
and let $n_{q}$ represent the number of Sylow subgroups of order $q^3$.

If we can show that either $n_p$ = $1$ or $n_{q}$ = 1 then we're done.

It follows that $n_p$ can equal {$1, q, q^2, q^3$} and $n_q$ can equal {$1, p$}.

Starting with $n_q$, if $n_q$ = 1 we're done. But suppose $n_q = p$, that implies that $p \equiv 1$ mod $q$. This shows that $p= qm + 1$ for some integer m > 0. But that's a contradiction because the hypothesis says that $q > p$ and this shows that $p > q$. Thus $n_q$ = 1 and $G$ has a normal subgroup.

Comment: This looks right to me.

Comment: This might sound nitpicky, but I don't think $n_q = p$ *implies* $p \equiv 1 (\bmod \, q)$, rather that is a consequence of the Sylow theorem itself.

Comment: tylerco816 is right. $n_q\mid p$ and $p\equiv 1\mod q$ are separate consequences of the Sylow theorems. But your proof is correct!

Comment: @BRayhaun Ahh okay. So would it sound better if I just say "by the third Sylow theorem, it follows that if $n_q = p$ then $p \equiv 1$ mod $q$?"

Comment: I'm sorry... you were actually right all along. Either is fine, I just misread the proof. :)

Comment: @Sam Whoops!  My apologies.  Yes, your original phrasing is correct.  I read that too fast.